# How do I count the number of users with a higher score than [userID]?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I have the following SQL code that returns the number of entries that have a higher score than a specific entry.

```
select (select count(*)
    from entries e2
    where e1.score < e2.score) + 1 as pos
from entries e1
where e1.ID = 36;
```

I am having a lot of trouble translating this into Sequelize.js. I have a solution that achieves this in 2 queries, but I'd like to do it in a single query.

```
this.dal.Entries.getPositionInList = (ID: number) => {
  return this.db.Entries.findOne({
    where: {
      ID: ID
    }
  }).then((entry: any) => {
    return this.db.Entries.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        score: {
          $gt: entry.score
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for something built in. But if it's the only way, it's the only way.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why you use an ORM if it is to make things more complicated :p Would my employers force me to use an ORM, I would use raw queries as soon as I need something more complicated than SELECT ... FROM ... :-)

Comment: Most of it is just simple selects and updates. I feel it's comfortable using ORMs with Typescript because I know what I'm getting without having to build it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be expressed in a number of ways. Maybe there is one you can transform into some sequelize code? (I don't know about it, I just hope what follows helps):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM entries
WHERE score >= (SELECT score FROM entries WHERE id = 36);


SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY score DESC)
FROM entries
ORDER BY id <> 36
LIMIT 1;


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM entries s1
LEFT JOIN entries s2 ON s2.score >= s1.score
WHERE s1.id = 36;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to convert both the first and second ones without success. I think the solution will come in the form of a RAW query, as you pointed out earlier.

Comment: I also did extensive tests on the speed of the first and second solution you mentioned. Turns out the first is much quicker. O(n) vs. O(n*log(n)) as one can be done with a single sweep, while the other is sorting. // Just a side-note

Comment: Yup, actually the second one computes the rank of each id then keeps only the first one, now that you say it it was to be expected that it would be slower, thanks for pointing it out :-)